# please am trying to make a condition of if x and y is ..... do this or that

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

if UpMove > DownMove and UpMove > 0, then +DM = UpMove, else +DM = 0

and this is what I have been trying

`df_move["+DI"] = np.where(df_move["upmove"] > df_move["downmove"] & 0 , df_move["upmove"], 0 )`

and I am get this error msg

> TypeError: Cannot perform 'and_' with a dtyped [float64] array and
> scalar of type [bool]

PLEASE what will I do

Comment: It's hard to answer your question as it doesn't follow the best practices of SO. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and work on a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: use: `print(df_move.dtypes)` and paste output here.

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtyped'

Comment: are you sure you wrote it right ? use **dtypes** instead of **dtyped**

Comment: high        float64
low         float64
close       float64
upmove      float64
downmove    float64
PDI         float64
dtype: object
​

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using np.where function wrong. Try this:

```
df_move["+DI"] = np.where((df_move["upmove"] > df_move["downmove"]) & (df_move["upmove"] > 0), df_move["upmove"], 0 )
```